# Prove that $F^*$ times $I_n$ is normal in $GL_n(F)$

Tags: group-theory

Could someone help with a proof:
 $F^*$ $I_n$ is normal in $GL_n(F)$.

---

Notice GL maps to F*:

$det:GL_n(F) \mapsto F^*$ by the determinant map.

And notice it maps back:

$F^* \mapsto GL_n(F)$ by  ($a \mapsto aI_n$) where $a \epsilon F^*$

Also note:

Not dot product (so $F^*I_n$ is not a scalar vector, it is a diagonal matrix)

Answer (score 1):

If by $\,\Bbb F^*\cdot I_n\,$ you mean the subgroup of all the non-zero scalar matrices then just check that this subgroup is just the center of $\,GL_n(\Bbb F)\,$...

Comment: Actually no sorry not $F^*$ dot $I_n$. It would be The matrix with only diagonal entries, like for instance if n=3 then:
$[a 0 0]
[0 a 0]
[0 0 a]$  where $a \epsilon F*$

Comment: Well, *actually* your example **is** a scalar matrix...

Comment: And nobody meant that $\,\Bbb F^*\cdot I_n\,$ is "dot product".